# The number of (a,b,c,d) with following conditions ...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The number of (a,b,c,d) with following conditions ...

1) $0 \le a \le b \le c  \le d \le n$,( $n \in \Bbb{N} $)

2) $0 \le a \le b < c \le d \le n$ ,($ 1\le  n$)

I think for 1 we can consider the number of solutions of following equation

$a_1 +a_2 +...+a_n =4$ ,$0\le a_i$ that $a_i$ is the number of view of number i in (a,b,c,d), and answer is $\binom {n-1+4}{n-1} = \binom{n+3}{n-1} = \binom{n+3}{4}$, is it true ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are correct. Meanwhile..

For (1). We have $$0 \le a < b+1 < c+2 < d+3 \le n+3$$

For (2). We have $$0 \le a < b+1 < c+1 < d+2 \le n+2$$

The calculations are left to the reader.

Comment: Now the answer for 2 is $\binom{n+2}{4}$.